# How to use MathType plugin in CKEditor 5 using ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5, mathtype, wiris

I have installed three packages:

1. @ckeditor/ckeditor5-react
2. @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic
3. @wiris/mathtype-ckeditor5/src/plugin

I'm able to setup simple ckeditor5 but don't know how to use MathType plugin in this editor.

Here is my sample code:

```
<CKEditor
  data={input.value}
  editor={ClassicEditor}
  onChange={(event, editor) => {
    return input.onChange(editor.getData());
  }}
/>;
```

Can anyone explain how i can use this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Here's [a link](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/installing-plugins.html) you should see to understand how to add a plugin to ckeditor.

TL;DR: You should create a new build containing your plugin (in your case MathType plugin), the easiest way to do it is using their [online builder](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/), then you can use that build that you generated instead of `@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic` for example.

I have already done this work and published it to npm, you can install it with:

`npm install ckeditor5-classic-with-mathtype`

Here's an example of using it with react:

```
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import ClassicEditor from 'ckeditor5-classic-with-mathtype';

...

render() {
        return (
                <CKEditor
                    editor={ClassicEditor}
                    config={{
                        toolbar: {
                            items: [
                                'heading', 'MathType', 'ChemType',
                                '|',
                                'bold',
                                'italic',
                                'link',
                                'bulletedList',
                                'numberedList',
                                'imageUpload',
                                'mediaEmbed',
                                'insertTable',
                                'blockQuote',
                                'undo',
                                'redo'
                            ]
                        },
                    }}
                    data="<p>Hello from CKEditor 5 with MathType!</p>"
                    onInit={editor => {
                        // You can store the "editor" and use when it is needed.
                        // console.log( 'Editor is ready to use!', editor );
                    }}
                />
        );
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Idriss AIT HAFID, It really helped, Saved my day

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: @IdrissAITHAFID, This works great with classic editor. What if I want to use the inline editor. Is there any plugin or module i can use. Inline editor with mathtype.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ckeditor5-build-classic-mathtype, a package which customizes classic editor build, which adds mathtype plugin.

```
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react'
import ClassicEditor from 'ckeditor5-build-classic-mathtype'

...

render() {
        return (
                <CKEditor
                    editor={ClassicEditor}
                    data="<p>Hello from CKEditor 5 with MathType!</p>"
                    onInit={editor => {
                        // You can store the "editor" and use when it is needed.
                        // console.log( 'Editor is ready to use!', editor );
                    }}
                />
        )
    }
```

Comment: Issue is how to use full MathType edior and urrently i'm getting 4-5 symobls in editor. I have taken subscription of wiris but don't know where to use keys.

Comment: Using the package, you can add a math formula in your editor right?

Comment: After using this package i can get math-editor with some functionality but i need complete formulas which wiris provided for mathType editor .check below url

http://www.wiris.com/en/mathtype

Comment: yes, that is what this package provides. what functionalities is left? when you click the square root icon you will see a mathtype editor.

Comment: Yes i can see math type editor but like this: https://ibb.co/YydF2nk

Comment: No that shouldn't be, I think it may be because of your internet connection.

Comment: Not an internet connection issue. Mathtype editor is not free need to take subscription for this.

Comment: No I don't think, I don't have a subscription but it is working for me.

Comment: When i started working on the MathType editor it was working correctly but after few days it will show only 4-5 formulas. Now i have installed your package still i'm getting same formulas.

Answer (score 0):

I have used MathType Editor in ReactJs using Javascript.

Here is the steps:

1. Include  in index.html
2. render normal text area in the component

```
<textarea name="question" id="question" cols="100" rows="6"></textarea>
```

3. use below code in componentDidMount function :

```
let ED = window.CKEDITOR;
    let mathElements = [
          'math',
          'maction',
          'maligngroup',
          'malignmark',
          'menclose',
          'merror',
          'mfenced',
          'mfrac',
          'mglyph',
          'mi',
          'mlabeledtr',
          'mlongdiv',
          'mmultiscripts',
          'mn',
          'mo',
          'mover',
          'mpadded',
          'mphantom',
          'mroot',
          'mrow',
          'ms',
          'mscarries',
          'mscarry',
          'msgroup',
          'msline',
          'mspace',
          'msqrt',
          'msrow',
          'mstack',
          'mstyle',
          'msub',
          'msup',
          'msubsup',
          'mtable',
          'mtd',
          'mtext',
          'mtr',
          'munder',
          'munderover',
          'semantics',
          'annotation',
          'annotation-xml'
      ];

    ED.plugins.addExternal( 'ckeditor_wiris',  'https://www.wiris.net/demo/plugins/ckeditor/', 'plugin.js' );

    ED.replace( 'question', {
        extraPlugins: 'ckeditor_wiris',
        // For now, MathType is incompatible with CKEditor file upload plugins.
        removePlugins: 'filetools,uploadimage,uploadwidget,uploadfile,filebrowser,easyimage',
        height: 320,
        // Update the ACF configuration with MathML syntax.
        extraAllowedContent: mathElements.join( ' ' ) + '(*)[*]{*};img[data-mathml,data-custom-editor,role](Wirisformula)'
    } );
```

If you want to check Ml tags in the react component. Need to load a script in the component:

```
const script = document.createElement("script");
script.src ='https://www.wiris.net/demo/plugins/app/WIRISplugins.js?viewer=image;
script.async = true;
document.body.appendChild(script);
```