# How to render CKEditor4 wiris MathML formula in react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor, mathjax, mathml

I'm trying to render MathML into the DOM. But it's not displaying correctly as shown in the Editor.

> I'm using **CKEditor4**

Let me just add the code below so you can understand what I have tried

**App.js file:**

```
import React from "react";
import CKEditor from "ckeditor4-react";

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            data: "",
        };
        CKEditor.editorUrl =
            "https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.16.0/standard-all/ckeditor.js";
    }

    onEditorChange = (evt) => {
        this.setState({
            data: evt.editor.getData(),
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <CKEditor
                    data={this.state.data}
                    onChange={this.onEditorChange}
                    config={{
                        extraPlugins: "ckeditor_wiris",
                        removePlugins:
                            "filetools,uploadimage,uploadwidget,uploadfile,filebrowser,easyimage",
                        allowedContent: true,
                    }}
                    onBeforeLoad={(CKEDITOR) => {
                        CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal(
                            "ckeditor_wiris",
                            "/mathtype-ckeditor4/",
                            "plugin.js"
                        );
                    }}
                />

                <div className="editor-preview">
                    <h2>Rendered content</h2>
                    <div
                        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.data }}
                    ></div>
                    <p>
                        <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
                            <mi>x</mi>
                            <mo>=</mo>
                            <mfrac>
                                <mrow>
                                    <mo>-</mo>
                                    <mi>b</mi>
                                    <mo>&#177;</mo>
                                    <msqrt>
                                        <msup>
                                            <mi>b</mi>
                                            <mn>2</mn>
                                        </msup>
                                        <mo>-</mo>
                                        <mn>4</mn>
                                        <mi>a</mi>
                                        <mi>c</mi>
                                    </msqrt>
                                </mrow>
                                <mrow>
                                    <mn>2</mn>
                                    <mi>a</mi>
                                </mrow>
                            </mfrac>
                        </math>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
        <meta
            name="description"
            content="Web site created using create-react-app"
        />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
        <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
        <title>React App</title>

        <!-- MathJax library to render MathML in HTML -->
        <script
            type="text/javascript"
            async
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"
        ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

> Since Chrome doesn't support MathML, I have added MathJax library in the header section

The MathJax library works fine if I paste the MathML directly into the html. But the MathML generated from CKEditor is not displaying correctly.

Please check the below image.

[Result preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfEdU.png)

**Expected result:**

Render the formula exactly like the editor

**Actual result:**

Content generated from editor are not rendering properly. But pasting the mathml directly into the HTML are rendering properly as expected.

Here is the Sandbox link as requested...

[Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-clarke-uv1uo?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&view=preview)

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: you need to pass ClassicEditor as edit prop to CKEditor . can you try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61230962/how-to-use-mathtype-plugin-in-ckeditor-5-using-reactjs

Comment: @LakshmanKambam I'm using CKEditor4, it doesn't requires to add editor as a prop

Comment: can you provide codesandbox link for this.

Comment: @LakshmanKambam Done, check now

Comment: sure let me check.

Answer (score 0):

> If you are using just a JS frontend without plugin services, you might
> link WIRISplugins.js directly from our servers, like so:

No need MathJax library. Add this script to your head:

```
<script src="https://www.wiris.net/demo/plugins/app/WIRISplugins.js?viewer=image"></script>
```

refer to this:
https://docs.wiris.com/en/mathtype/integrations/html/ckeditor